# WPF PropertyChangedEvent is always null

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have a user control with the following elements

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="150" Height="150">
        <TextBlock Text="hai"> </TextBlock>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding DeviceName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceID, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I am setting the DataContext like below

```
 public partial class WorkFlowManager : UserControl
{
    public WorkFlowManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new WorkFlowManagerVM();
    }
}
```

And my WorkflowManagerVM implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class WorkFlowManagerVM : INotifyPropertyChanged

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
       if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
```

The Propertchanged event is always null. Is there any problem the way I set the DataContext. This User control will be inside MainWindow. Not sure what has gone wrong.

Comment: User control doesn't have to have his own datacontext

Comment: As a note, `Mode=TwoWay` on the Text Binding of a TextBlock is pointless.

Comment: I'd even say a UserControl *must not* have its own view model. It should instead operate on a view model that is provided by its parent element, i.e. a Window or Page.

Comment: How do you know that the PropertyChanged event of this private view model instance is null? How do you access it? I.e. how do you set one of its properties that would call RisePropertyChanged? I'd bet you are looking at some other instance of the view model class, i.e. not this private one.

Comment: i am setting one of its property in different viewmodel.  And i carete new instance for  that. Both are two different instances then?

Comment: Sure. This is exactly the reason why a UserControl must not have its own view model. Simply remove `this.DataContext = new WorkFlowManagerVM();`